# Sort combobox items from datasource (GetScheme("Tables")

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting, combobox

Noob here, when I run this:

```
connection.Open()

Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"
Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME"
Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = Me.connection.GetSchema("TABLES")
```

The combobox is populated with table names but they are not in alphabetical order

Sort using behavior--->sorted property does not work either

Thanks

Comment: Weird cannot get your problem. What kind of database are you using?

Comment: @Steve - SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't get the correct ordering for your tables, then you can simply force it acting on the DefaultView property of the table returned by GetSchema

```
Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"
Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME"

Dim schema = con.GetSchema("TABLES")
schema.DefaultView.Sort = "TABLE_NAME"
Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = schema.DefaultView
```

Comment: Thank you that worked - how do I mark this solved by you?